# get path for imported database in app's resource bundle swift

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, swift, resourcebundle

I have imported a Database that I made with a database browser into my swift. Now my problem is getting the path to this database. I have a FMDB wrapper in the app as well.

When I click on the resource file the `Full Path` description is displayed and I can use that as the path directly and I have no problem querying the database but I am not sure if that full path can be shipped with the app because it looks like it goes specifically through this computer. I tried using `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyDatabaseName", ofType: "sqlite")` but that returns `nil`

Basic Question: How do i get the path for my resource file/database file so that I can use it?

Thanks for any help! Super Desperate!

Comment: You have to use `NSBundle.mainBundle` but you may need to add in a directory. Where is it in the app bundle? Provide the full path so we can help. You will of course not be able to write to the db in the app bundle.

Comment: This is solely for queries on the database, and the queries are in SQL! here is the full path `/Users/thomaskutay/Desktop/Learning C with Rossi/Insight/Insight_1/Insight_1/Insight1-0.db`.

Comment: That is not in the app, you need to add the db to the app in Xcode, Drag the db file it to the file list and select to add to project. Then your `pathForResource` should work.

Comment: That's what I did and i just deleted it and did it again. I even made sure that it was in the apps copy bundle resources and it was. Then i deleted it again and added it through the copy bundle resources and it still has the same path of `/Users/thomaskutay/Desktop/Learning C with Rossi/Insight/Insight_1/Insight1-0.db` Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the future, you can also go to the "Build Phases" tab of the "Target" settings, and then look at the "Copy Bundle Resources" list. Your db should appear there and add it there if it's not. Or you can select the db in the project navigator panel on the left and then open the "document inspector" in the right panel (e.g. by hitting option-command-1) and then look at the "Target Membership" section and make sure there's a checkmark next to the appropriate target (i.e. the main one for your app).

Comment: Oh god No! i meant thats what I did and I still have the problem! it has the same path and I cant find the right path through the `NSBundle`

Comment: The app is called `Insight_1`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using the path in the Mac file system to the sopurce version, don't use that, you need the path in the device file system (or the simulator file system).

On the device it will look something *like* this:

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/953D9CCB-40A2-4587-9A75-531DCE3A2DD3/AppName.app/MyDatabaseName.sqlite

On the simulator it will look something *like* this:

> /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/56992263-5158-4AF5-B0CC-83E31982BB3E/data/Applications/560EEF55-2F15-4094-B20C-FF3B839AF7C2/AppName.app/MyDatabaseName.sqlite
>   There is a path to the file in the app file system.

Here is how to find it:

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. In Xcode Menu : Window : Projects
3. Select your project on the left column
4. At the right end of Derived Data click on the arrow
   [image]
5. The Finder will open the Derived Data folder
6. Double click your app's folder
7. Navigate the directory tree to Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
8. You will see the file .app
   [image]
9. This is the app bundle directory.
10. Right click (<kbd>control</kbd> click) and select Show Package Contents
    [image]
11. Find the DB file in this folder or a sub directory.
12. The Bundle path is the path from this folder to the db file.

Sample code to create db path:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *bundlePath = [bundle bundlePath];
NSLog(@"bundlePath: %@", bundlePath);
NSString *dbPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"<path in bundle>"];
NSLog(@"dbPath: %@", dbPath);
```

There are other ways to find the path (such as knowing where it is a priori) and other ways to get the path in the app but not knowing your exact configuration tis should work for you.